# Prolog set a list based on query values

Tags: prolog

Is there a way to get a list by results of a query?

eg:

```
getPairs(x,y):-
    v1(x), v2(y);
    v11(x), v22(y).

v1(10). v2(20). v11(12). v22(22).
```

then how can i use getPairs to make a list of pairs that I could then feed into another query

```
[[10,20],[12,22]].
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there

```
getPairs([[X1,X2], [Y1,Y2]):-
    v1(X1), v2(X2),
    v11(Y1), v22(Y2).

v1(10). v2(20). v11(12). v22(22).
```

In getPairs/1, you write what pattern you want as result. Note that logic variables are written with capitals.